# React-Native Setup: Could not normalize path for this file

Tags: android, android-studio, reactjs, react-native, native

I am just beginning my work with React-Native. After initializing the directory for my project and starting react in one terminal, I use the command react-native run-android to start the emulator. The emulator fails with the error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\dannyd1221\Desktop\School\CIS350\Weekdays\android\app\build.gradle' line: 110
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\dannyd1221\Desktop\School\CIS350\Weekdays\android\C:Usersdannyd1221AppDataLocalAndroidSdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt'.

Clearly the path to proguard-android.txt is incorrect, but I'm not sure where that path is being set. Any ideas as to how this can be fixed?

Comment: `Aandroid SDK Build-Tools` must be at least `23.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error. 
Worked when i Replaced
C:\Users\dannyd1221\Desktop\School\CIS350\Weekdays\android\
with 
C:/Users/dannyd1221/Desktop/School/CIS350/Weekdays/android/